# How to calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2}ab\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2{\theta}+b^2\cos^2{\theta}}d\theta$

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate this integral:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}ab\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2{\theta}+b^2\cos^2{\theta}}d\theta
$$

I tried let $t=\tan{\theta}$, but still too complex to do. I also tried to put sin and cos into the root, it doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Why $t = \tan \theta$ when you are still left with the thing in the square root?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) before you ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral simplifies to $$ab\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(\theta)+b^2\cos^2(\theta)} \,d\theta.$$
We can then make the substitution $u=a^2\sin^2(\theta)+b^2\cos^2(\theta)$, with $du=\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(2a^2-2b^2) d\theta.$

This leads to $$\frac{ab}{2a^2-2b^2}\int_{u=b^2}^{u=a^2} \sqrt{u} \,du.$$

The rest is relatively simple:
$$\frac{ab}{2a^2-2b^2}[\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}]_{b^2}^{a^2}=\frac{ab}{3(a^2-b^2)}(a^3-b^3)$$

Note that $a$ and $b$ must simultaneously not be equal to zero.

Comment: This person hasn't shown any of their own work, so wait till they show their work to answer their question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't realize I can remove square root directly!